# Can't get rid of extra space between 2 lines

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't reduce the "empty" space between 2 lines ([**see picture and this link for live demo**](http://dev.be-pixel.com/db-alt/)  ). I've tried many things (line-height, margin top and bottom, padding, etc.) but without success. This one, for some reason is tricky. I tried to reproduce the issue on JSFiddle without success.

**Edit**: I have now removed the `<br>` between the 2 pairs of p tags but it created a new issue: both lines (both pair of p tags) are now displayed as one single line

[image: displaying the error in the image]

**CSS code from css/mettile.css**

```
.tile-five {
    width: 400px;
    height: 46px;
    display: block;  
    margin-right: 0px;
    border-radius: 20px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}


.tile-five:hover {
    outline: solid 4px #dadada;
}

.tile-five-small {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    display: block;
}

.tile-five-small:hover {
    outline: solid 4px #dadada;
}

.tile-five-text-area {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f2F2F2;
    padding-left: 12px;

}

.tile-five-text-area label {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

.tile-five-text-area p {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 8px 5px 5px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="sub-header">
        <div class="sub-header-wrapper">
          <div class="left">
            <h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1>
            <h2>Votre dfds dfdsf dsfds (dfds fds) à Luiotkjkjkjy</h2>
          </div>
          <!-- End Left -->
          <div class="right"><a id="MetTileFive" class="tile-five" href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
            <div>
            <p><strong>Actualité</strong></p>
            <br>
            <p>Découvrez <strong>Ladkkiu</strong>, un concept unique au Luiotsddqsdykjkjkj</p>
          </div>
            <div>
            <p><strong>Actualité</strong></p>
            <br>
            <p>Atelier dfdsf à Luioty le 03 Mars 2014. Réservez vite!</p>
          </div>
            </a></div>
          <!-- End Right --> 
        </div>
        <!-- End Wrapper --> 

      </div>
      <!-- End sub-header-->
```

Comment: Where's your HTML?  Is there a <br> or <p> tag in there?  A <pre> tag?

Comment: Please don't link to your site but to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: There is a `<br />` separating those two elements.

Comment: You have a  <br> between the elements.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wanted to put a <br> otherwise the second line of text would not go to the next line even with 2 pairs of p tags. Is there another possibility?

Comment: On a side note: `</div>
            </a></div>' is also incorrect. It can also cause formatting issues

Comment: Why are you floating paragraph tags to the left?

Comment: Thanks. It is a plugin called Mettile, not sure why it was made like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the < br > between your < p > tags, as that creates the blank space between your lines.

if the code looks like this you should be fine, I just looked at it in chrome and the lines of text were on two lines not one.

```
<div class="tile-five-text-area">
        <p><strong>Actualité</strong></p>

        <p>Découvrez <strong>Ladkkiu</strong>, un concept unique au Luiotsddqsdykjkjkj</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it fixes 2 issue but then my second line of text goes on the same line as the first one (despite the fact that it is wrapped into a second pair of p tags). How come?

Comment: Thanks - I removed the <br> and shortened the text an now you can see that both lines are on the same line (link of my webpage has been updated). Why is that? Thanks

Comment: @Greg because you removed the <br/>

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought each <p></p> would create a new line. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The "empty" space between 2 lines can be reduced with:

```
#sub-header .right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 4px;
    }
```

or

```
#sub-header p {
line-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: @user689 please edit also small typos and other problems you see in the answer next time, not only the code formatting

Answer (score 1):

To do this there is a special property in css called `line-height` you can set it to 1em to reduce height.[more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp).
And remember only use em or pixels. [why?](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/paragraphspacing.html) .
This way it is possible to control the vertical distance as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two separate p tags rather try writing with a single p tag

```html
<div>
            <p><strong>Actualité</strong>
            <br />
            Découvrez <strong>Ladkkiu</strong>, un concept unique au Luiotsddqsdykjkjkj</p>
</div>
```

Elements like p and h1 are block elements and hence insert some space between consecutive lines.